# When trying to log in with another facebook user it says there is an error in the console log

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, authentication

When I login with my facebook account I am able to get all of the objects(like the statuses and email).  When I try authenticating with another user it doesn't show anything but an error. PLEASE HELP?!?!

```
function Login(){
            FB.login(function(response){
                if(response.authResponse){
                    alert(response.authResponse.accessToken);

                    console.log('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;

                    var postsURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + uid + "/statuses?limit=20&access_token=" + accessToken;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: postsURL,
                        method: 'GET',
                        datatype: "jsonp",
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log("Success!");
                        }, error: function(status){
                            console.log("Unsuccessful! With status: " + status);
                        }

                    });
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $.getJSON(postsURL, function(data){
                            var name = data.data;
                            for(var i=0; i<=19; i++){
                                console.log(i);
                                console.log('message: ' + name[i].message + '\ntime: ' + name[i].updated_time);
                            }

                        });
                    });
                    successButtonRemoval();
                } else{
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            },{scope: 'email,read_stream,user_status'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to log out as yourself. Subsequently, re-authenticate with the other user's credentials to get a new access token.

It also appears that you have a couple of other issues. Mainly, you are working too hard. You are binding the fetch to the document ready event, after you are making an asynchronous call. This can result in wild behavior, and duplicate code if you are trying to do the same thing in each call back.

Try logging in and access the SDK via their api call (similar to the api examples from the SDK).

```
function LoginAndDoOtherThings(){
        FB.login(function(response){
            if(response.authResponse){
                console.log("Yay we are in!");
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        console.log("here is my info:");
                        console.log(response);
                        //do other things.
                });
                successButtonRemoval();
            } else{
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        },{scope: 'email,read_stream,user_status'});
```

'

Please read the documentation about the login flow for the web sdk.

[Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0)